# Transformations generated by asymptotic Killing vectors

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, tensor-calculus, research-level, variational-calculus

I want to know how tensors transform under the transformations generated by Killing vectors. In particular I am interested in asymptotic symmetries and asymptotic Killing vectors. In order to understand the calculations better and have a proper example for what I am trying to understand I refer to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08346).

In Eq. 3.3 the Killing vector field near a the bifurcation sphere was derived
$$
  \xi^{\pm} = \pm x^{\pm} T^\pm(x^A) + \mathcal{O}(x^3),\quad 
  \xi^{\pm} = Y^{A}(x^B) + \mathcal{O}(x^2),
$$
where $x^A=(\theta,\phi)$. Next, in Eq. 3.4a the transformation for one of the leading order functions $\eta(x^A)$ of the metric expansion near the bifurcation sphere is given
$$
  \delta_{\xi}\eta=Y^A \partial_A \eta+(T^+-T^-)\eta.
$$
This appears odd, as the function $\eta$ does not depend on $x^+$ and $x^-$ and therefore shouldn't depend on $T^\pm$ in my opinion. On the other hand similar deviations from my expected results are present for 1-forms and 2-forms in Eqs. 3.4c and 3.4d and also in chapter 4 were similar calculations are done.

My expectation was that the that the transformation behaviour is given by the Lie derivative with respect to the Killing vector field which would yield
$$
  \mathcal{L_\xi}\eta=Y^A \partial_A.
$$
Probably I am misunderstanding what is happening or what the results in the referred paper mean. I would appreciate someone has an idea of what $\delta_{\xi}\eta$ means and share it with me.

Comment: Coudl it be that you are thinking that $T^\pm$ depend on $x^\pm$? But they don't. As to what to expect for the transformation of one of the functions in the components of the asymptotic metric, they are not Lie derivatives in general. There could be extra terms. The transformation $\delta \eta$ just means "read that is the new $\eta$ in the transformed metric and substract the original one".

Answer (score 1):

$\eta$ is not a function on the manifold, but rather a component of the metric tensor as written in (3.2). The metric transforms under an infinitesimal diffeomorphism like $L_{\xi}g_{\mu \nu}= \xi^{\alpha}\nabla_{\alpha}g_{\mu \nu}+\nabla_{\mu}\xi_{\nu}+\nabla_{\nu}\xi_{\mu} $ (one can use any connection here).
The notation in the paper might be confusing in this case, but one just computes the RHS and then the change in $\eta$ is denoted by $\delta_{\xi}\eta$.